# What is the equivalent to end="" in a return function?

Tags: python

I'm in the process of self-teaching Python, and would love to know if there's an equivalent to end="" used with print() for a return function. For instance:

```
def shape(num,x):
    for col in reversed(range(num)):
            for row in range(col+1):
                print(x,end="")
            print()
```

Gives me the result I want, but how would I use a return function to provide me with the same results?

Comment: What is a return function?

Comment: What does this mean? What is a "return function", and what would "end" be doing in it?

Comment: I think he means the return statement - I could see how this would be confusing to a new programmer.

Answer (score 4):

Are you asking how to return a string? Here is one way, following the same form you used:

```
def shape(num,x):
    result = ''
    for col in reversed(range(num)):
            for row in range(col+1):
                result += x 
            result += '\n'
    return result

print (shape(4, '*'), end="")
```

Using `+=` on strings is bad form, however. As you continue to improve your code, check out list comprehensions and the `str.join()` function.

You might end up with something like this:

```
    return '\n'.join('*'*(col+1) for col in reversed(range(num)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Print the return value:

```
def shape(num):
    x = 0
    for col in reversed(range(num)):
        for row in range(col+1):
           x += row 
   return x
print(shape(82))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way you could do this is using a generator function:

```
def shape(num, x):
    for col in reversed(range(num)):
        yield x * (col + 1)

for line in shape(4, '*'):
    print(line)
```

Note: the generator function does basically the same thing as the generator expresion Robᵩ has shown(inside the `'\n'.join()`), but it's worth knowing how to create a generator function for more complicated cases.